# What is the realtime equivalent of the module r8169?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, real-time, xenomai

From here: http://www.xenomai.org/index.php/RTnet:Installation_%26_Testing#Testing_with_a_single_node_.28local_loopback.29

> TODO: simplify the following steps.
>    - Then you need to edit the file rtnet.conf under the /usr/local/rtnet/etc folder for the correct setup to run RTnet. Edit the following parameters:
>    - Set the host up as master or slave depending on how you are going to use it.
>    **- The RT_DRIVER should be the realtime equivalent of the module you removed nl. rt_8139too.**

Kernel: 2.6.38.8

```
linux-y3pi:~ # ethtool -i eth0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version:
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
```

After RTnet installation I get:

```
linux-y3pi:/usr/local/rtnet/modules # ls
rt_8139too.ko rtcfg.ko rt_eepro100.ko rt_loopback.ko rtnet.ko rtudp.ko
rtcap.ko      rt_e1000.ko  rtipv4.ko       rtmac.ko        rtpacket.ko  tdma.ko
```

How to find what corresponds to `r8169`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last source distribution, (`rtnet-0.9.12.tar.bz2`), I can see `rtnet-0.9.12/drivers/experimental/rt_r8169.c`, so the `rt_` nomenclature remains. The module filename should be `rt_r8169.ko`. It's not there either because it wasn't compiled, or because it *failed* to compile (it *is* under the ‘experimental’ subdirectory, after all). I see there's an `--enable-r8169` option in the `configure` script. Did you supply it?

Comment: thanks very much, I just had a talk with the Jan Kizka. He said this experimental version may cause problems. :( Scroll down here:http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4FD063DA.3020004%40web.de&forum_name=rtnet-users , BTW, **Should I install some other kernel which has 8139 driver?**

Comment: To what end? If your NIC is provided by an RTL8169, the only way to proceed further would be to get a supported NIC on an add-on card (e.g. an RTL8139, assuming you can find one). Like the mailing list says, 8139≠8169. Alternatively, you can look through the SF Bug Tracker for those ‘known problems’ (or ask about them), and see if you can live with them. If it crashes the kernel, then probably not. If it fails to light up the LEDs on the Ethernet jack, it's probably a little bit better.

Comment: Thanks Alexio, this is the network card I have `Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 01)` BTW, I don't think using the experimental driver would be much sensible task for the hard real time things specially when the developer himself doesn't recommend it.

Comment: Well, just for the sake I installed that new driver and recompiled the rtnet. Thanks to you. The error messages I used to get previously have now reduced. But, still I wish to understand what exactly is happening when those messages come so I'll form a new question for that.